# Get dynamic string from a website in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the best way to grab a single string of text from a website and display in an application?

I was looking at somehow using Parse Cloud to do some kind of scheduled job and then the app would query Parse, but that seems like quite a lot of overhead for the simple need of grabbing one or two dynamic strings.

I use objective-C - Xcode 6.

Thanks all.

Comment: You want to genereate a web service from a web page? Thats want you meant?

Comment: Hi Karlo - no, really what I want is to grab a single line of text and display it in a label.  <strong class = "table_cell_heading">  "Ball numbers" </strong>    I want that text in between.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a network request in an iOS app, take a look at the [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/) APIs to fetch the URL. You can then process the content however you'd like. You can also use a networking library like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

An example of fetching a text document using NSURLSession would be something like:

```
NSURL *urlToFetch = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.ipify.org/?format=txt"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:urlToFetch completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Handle error
        NSLog(@"Error fetching: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    } else {
        NSStringEncoding stringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
        if (response.textEncodingName) {
            CFStringEncoding IANAEncoding = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((__bridge CFStringRef)response.textEncodingName);
            if (IANAEncoding != kCFStringEncodingInvalidId) {
                stringEncoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(IANAEncoding);
            }
        }

        NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:stringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"The content is: %@", content);
    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
```